# Why my discord bot hosted on heroku is turning off randomly?

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord

I have a Discord bot written on JS and hosted on Heroku. Since 2 days it is turning off randomly every 5-30 minutes. When it turns off I restart (turning off and on again) the dyno (it is a worker dyno, supposed to be 24/7) and it turns on, but again after the mentioned time it turns off, only the bot, the dyno is still on. I haven't modified any code, it happened randomly, I have other friends with bots hosted on Heroku and they don't have problems. I'm using Heroku free plan with worker dino. Also, the commands don't work when it is online by Heroku, they only work when I run the bot by `node index.js`.

I tried changing options from Heroku, seeing the log, modifying some code even putting a code that I found in internet that pings your bot every 5 minutes but nothing.

This is my log:

```
2019-04-19T12:14:34.586658+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
2019-04-19T12:14:34.586660+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
2019-04-19T12:14:34.586661+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
2019-04-19T12:14:34.586663+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
2019-04-19T12:14:34.586665+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
2019-04-19T12:14:34.671352+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-04-19T12:14:34.652558+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-19T12:41:06.879262+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to down
2019-04-19T12:41:11.663020+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-04-19T12:41:12.348731+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-04-19T12:41:14.194602+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command goodmorning
2019-04-19T12:41:14.198617+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command goodnight
2019-04-19T12:41:14.199576+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command hug
2019-04-19T12:41:14.200215+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command kamehameha
2019-04-19T12:41:14.200930+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command kickballs
2019-04-19T12:41:14.201643+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command kiss
2019-04-19T12:41:14.206727+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command scare
2019-04-19T12:41:14.207865+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command help
2019-04-19T12:41:14.208523+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command info
2019-04-19T12:41:14.208951+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command invite
2019-04-19T12:41:14.209455+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command nikonikoni
2019-04-19T12:41:14.209917+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command ping
2019-04-19T12:41:14.210335+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command running
2019-04-19T12:41:14.211635+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command servers
2019-04-19T12:41:14.212116+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command test
2019-04-19T12:41:14.212553+00:00 app[worker.1]: Attempting to load command version
2019-04-19T12:41:17.072384+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ready to serve in 600 channels on 22 servers, for a total of 16185 users.
```

And when it crashes, it appears this:

```
2019-04-19T12:45:25.500389+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=dangerdiscord.herokuapp.com request_id=bb4b7f4f-d3c4-441a-add4-18b85a78e8cb fwd="3.90.103.169" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2019-04-19T12:45:27.764983+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/events/guildMemberAdd.js:2
2019-04-19T12:45:27.764996+00:00 app[worker.1]:   const defaultChannel = member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES"));
2019-04-19T12:45:27.764998+00:00 app[worker.1]:                                                                                       ^
2019-04-19T12:45:27.764999+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765001+00:00 app[worker.1]: ReferenceError: guild is not defined
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765003+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at member.guild.channels.find.channel (/app/events/guildMemberAdd.js:2:87)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765004+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Map.find (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Collection.js:506:11)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765006+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at module.exports (/app/events/guildMemberAdd.js:2:48)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765007+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Client.emit (events.js:189:13)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765009+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Guild._addMember (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js:1192:19)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765011+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at GuildMemberAddHandler.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildMemberAdd.js:12:13)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765012+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765013+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765014+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.765015+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
2019-04-19T12:45:27.903986+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-04-19T12:45:27.889791+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: Your error is `at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" `

Comment: Line 2 of /app/events/guildMemberAdd.js is trying to use a variable named `guild` that is not defined when receiving requests to add a guild member. A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be useful.

Comment: I thought it can be that, ZUNJAE, but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: I have free dynos, but instead of the web one, im using the worker, and also, i have 1 friend that have heroku free and the worker dyn0o and his bot never shuts down

Comment: I'm sure you've seen this elsewhere, but heroku is not for discord bot hosting (Source: ask in any bot development guild via Discord)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things to understand about Heroku:

1. If you use a web dyno, your bot will shut off after 30 minutes of inactivity, to make the bot run '24/7' you should use a worker dyno.
2. Heroku is a free service (unless you are paying,) so obviously they can't keep your bot online 100% of the time, they give you a free 550 hours per month of hosting (there are ~730 hours in a month.) If you add a credit card to your account, you can get another ~450 hours of hosting per month, which obviously is more hours than what is in a month, and they will NEVER charge anything to your credit card, they do this to ensure that you are a real human being.
3. Hours across multiple projects on Heroku are NOT project based, they are account based, so if you have a free account with 1000 hours per month, but have multiple projects hosted, those hours will NOT last you the full month.

EDIT: PS: Your issue is elsewhere, but since you are using Heroku, I figure that there things are necessary for you to understand, and if you are willing to spend money, I'd advise looking in to a stronger VPS that is intended for bot hosting. I would especially advise this since it seems that you have ~16,000 people using that bot, which could cause an overflow to Heroku/make your bot laggy and unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure heroku has a timeout if you are using the free version. Does it stop if it is in use or only when it's left?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and a workaround I'm using is to ping the bot (HTTP GET request in my case) every 30 minutes, destroy the client and login again.

The drawback is a downtime of a few seconds, but that's totally fine for my use case.